Integrating AVFoundation with WebRTC in iOS: How to Feed AVCaptureSession into RTCVideoCapturer?
I'm currently working on an iOS project where I'm using AVFoundation to capture video, and I want to integrate WebRTC functionality into this setup. Specifically, I'm using the GoogleWebRTC package.
Here's a snippet of my current setup:
private func setupAVCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .high

    guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
        print("Keine Kamera gefunden")
        return
    }

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fehler beim Hinzufügen der Kamera-Input: \(error)")
        return
    }

    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    print("Preview Layer hinzugefügt und konfiguriert")

    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }

    setupCapturer()

    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func setupCapturer() {
    let videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.videoSource()
    videoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)

    guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
        print("Keine Kamera gefunden")
        return
    }

    let formats = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: camera)
    guard let format = formats.first else {
        print("Keine unterstützten Formate gefunden")
        return
    }

    videoCapturer?.startCapture(with: camera, format: format, fps: 30)
}

While this setup captures video and displays it on a previewLayer, I'm struggling to pass the captured video frames from my AVCaptureSession to WebRTC's RTCVideoCapturer.
I understand that RTCCameraVideoCapturer is designed to work with camera devices directly, but I need to know how to either:

Pass the entire AVCaptureSession directly to WebRTC's capturer.
Feed individual frames from AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate to WebRTC for transmission.
Is there a recommended approach or any workaround that would allow me to use my existing AVCaptureSession while leveraging WebRTC's video streaming capabilities? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
